# What are some good heading fonts that pair with Merriweather?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, web-fonts

Right now we're using Open Sans, but I'm not a huge fan of it. It falls flat for me (maybe I'm wrong?).

We can choose from Google Fonts or *maybe* a $2.5-5k one-time purchase. We get a few million views a month and don't want to be tied to some subscription.

Comment: Do you really mean £2.5-5k?

Answer (score 1):

The common rule for font pairing... contrast. Merriweather is a Serif font, the best fonts for pairing would be San-Serif fonts.

Other Google Fonts to try:

- Lato
- Roboto
- Oswald
- Source Sans Pro

Non-Google Fonts:

- Future
- Helvetica
- Brandon Grotesk

Comment: I like Lato and Brandon. The latter much more.